# 90 degree phase difference in current between inductors

Tags: phase-shift

The schematic is a circuit I am designing. The current through the leg with the inductor and capacitor in series must be 90 degrees offset from the other leg. The rectified current pulses through both legs must be equal. How do I calculate the value of the capacitor?  - Disregard the 3rd (secondary) inductor.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this? Readers might be able to suggest other circuits to achieve the same result.

Comment: The objective is to get a 90 degrees phase shift between the rectified pulses for the primary coils. This will result in a third magnetic pulse which is out of phase with the two primaries.